# How to auto boot a rooted android device on charging [code req]

Tags: android, bootloader

How to auto boot a rooted android phone when it is dead and connected to the charger?

I know many people think its not possible as when the device is `OFF` and `ADB` isn't running. But it turns out that it is possible to write an application for rooted device.

There is an application for the same @[playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=auto.boot) to do just that.

I just want to make similar app. Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should google a bit

i guess your looking for something

similar to this?

**https://android.stackexchange.com/q/39899**

Mostly you will have to check the boot-sequence of multiple devices and code accordingly as each device will have different setups

for example the app you posted in your question works only for samsung devices

Answer (score 1):

I am researching for the same problem (Android 2.3, htc wildfire s), this are my investigation results:

It works! Unfortunaly it works, if you connect the phone without accumulator and after that insert the accu- now its autoboots. Connecting the phone with inserted accu or insert the accu in the unconnected phone does not work.

Not the result I hoped for  but maybe a hint for a pointer.

And I found a script solution: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39899/auto-boot-when-charger-connected-for-htc-magic

---

```
echo "echo skipping chargemon" > chargemon.script

adb pull /system/bin/chargemon chargemon.backup

adb push chargemon.script  /sqlite_stmt_journals

adb shell

$ cd /sqlite_stmt_journals
$ su
# mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
# cat chargemon.script > /system/bin/chargemon
# chmod 755 /system/bin/chargemon
# reboot -p
```